# SQL - INTERSECT with HAVING + MAX of a SUM

Tags: sql, sum, max, having

I have a final exam in databases and as I was solving some sample questions I came across some problems.

I have a many to many relationship between 2 tables.

```
Player                    PlayerTournament               Tournament
-------                  --------------------           -------------------
pk id_player             fk id_player                   pk id_tournament
name                     fk id_tournament               name
rank                     year                           city
country                  victories                      court_surface
                                                        tournament_type
```

What I have to do is:

1). List the players (name and country) who, in 2016, won at least one match in a clay tournament, but didn’t participate in any grass tournament.

2). List the players (name, country, total number of victories) with the greatest number of victories.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
1. SELECT P.NAME, P.COUNTRY
FROM Player P INNER JOIN PlayerTournament PT
ON P.ID_PLAYER= PT.ID_PLAYER
INNER JOIN Tournament T
ON T.ID_TOURNAMENT= PT.ID_TOURNAMENT
WHERE T.COURT_SURFACE="clay"
GROUP BY (something)
HAVING SUM(PT.VICTORIES)>=1
INTERSECT
(same select and inner joins)
WHERE T.COURT_SURFACE="grass"
GROUP BY (something)
HAVING COUNT(ID_PLAYER)=0

2.SELECT P.NAME, P.COUNTRY, SUM(PT.VICTORIES)
FROM Player P INNER JOIN PlayerTournament PT
ON P.ID_PLAYER= PT.ID_PLAYER
GROUP BY ...
HAVING sum of victories = max sum of victories
```

I don't know if the way i thought the problem is correct, I need help with the "having" statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: `INTERSECT` will not work, as `COUNT(ID_PLAYER)` will never be NULL.
You must switch to `EXCEPT` without `HAVING`.

Another standard solution for this type of query (same Select with different conditions) utilizes *conditional aggregation* where both conditions are moved into different CASEs:

```
SELECT P.NAME, P.COUNTRY
FROM Player P INNER JOIN PlayerTournament PT
ON P.ID_PLAYER= PT.ID_PLAYER
INNER JOIN Tournament T
ON T.ID_TOURNAMENT= PT.ID_TOURNAMENT
WHERE T.COURT_SURFACE IN ('clay', 'grass')
GROUP BY (something)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN T.COURT_SURFACE = 'clay' THEN PT.VICTORIES END)>=1
 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN T.COURT_SURFACE = 'grass' THEN PT.ID_PLAYER END)=0
```

Q2: This seems to ask for the *best player per country*, but your having can't be written directly as nested aggregates rare not allowed. You can use a Correlated Subquery instead:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT P.NAME, P.COUNTRY, SUM(PT.VICTORIES) AS sumVic
   FROM Player P INNER JOIN PlayerTournament PT
   ON P.ID_PLAYER= PT.ID_PLAYER
   GROUP BY ...
 )
SELECT *
FROM cte AS t1
WHERE sumVic = 
 ( SELECT MAX(sumVic)
   FROM cte AS t2 
   WHERE t1.ID_PLAYER = t2.ID_PLAYER
 )
```

Using more modern *Windowed Aggregate Functions* you can do the MAX-calculation in the same level:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT P.NAME, P.COUNTRY, SUM(PT.VICTORIES) AS sumVic,
      MAX(SUM(PT.VICTORIES)) OVER (PARTITION BY P.COUNTRY) AS maxVic
   FROM Player P INNER JOIN PlayerTournament PT
   ON P.ID_PLAYER= PT.ID_PLAYER
   GROUP BY ...
 )
SELECT *
FROM cte AS t1
WHERE sumVic = maxVic
```